# How to fix "viewport-fit=cover" for Chrome in iOS in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I am working on the responsive part of the website. The viewport on Safari iOS landscape orientation works great, but in Chrome it expands and moves sideways and still has the empty white slides on the side.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" fetchpriority="high">
```

How to fix that in Chrome iOS in landscape orientation?
The following html and css:

```js
function handleScroll() {
  const header = document.getElementById('header');
  const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
  const headerLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header-link h4');
  const contactButton = document.querySelector('.btn');

  if (scrollTop > 0) {
    header.classList.add('scrolled');
    logo.src = 'media/logo-white.png';
    headerLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.add('white-link');
    });
    contactButton.classList.add('scrolled-button');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('scrolled');
    logo.src = 'media/logo.png';
    headerLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove('white-link');
    });
    contactButton.classList.remove('scrolled-button');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

var hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
var headerRight = document.querySelector('.header-right');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (headerRight.classList.contains('active')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      headerRight.classList.remove('active');
    }, 50);
  } else {
    headerRight.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #042440;
  background: white;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/* Header End */

#hero-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
}


/* Header Start */

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  padding-left: 20%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0;
  padding-right: 3%;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #042440;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 44px;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.header-link {
  color: #042440;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 0;
}

.header-link h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.scrolled {
  background-color: #042440;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.white-link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: white;
}

.scrolled-button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #042440;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}


/* Hero Full Center Section - Left & Right Content Start */

.center-content-hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65% 35%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.center-content-hero-text-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 65vw;
  height: 95vh;
  gap: 8px;
}

.main-title-hero {
  display: grid;
  align-self: end;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: calc(5.5vw);
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: start;
}

.main-subtitle-hero {
  display: grid;
  align-self: start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: calc(1.5vw);
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: start;
  width: 80%;
}

.center-hero-img-container {
  display: grid;
  align-self: start;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.center-hero-img {
  display: grid;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 95vh;
  justify-self: end;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/* Hero Full Center Section - Left & Right Content End */


/* Hero Bottom Banner Section Start */

.strip-separator-text-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5vh;
  border-top: 1px solid #042440;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #042440;
}

.persona-banner {
  display: grid;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .header-left {
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .header-right.active {
    display: grid;
    transform: translateX(0);
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #042440;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .header-link {
    color: white;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    order: 2;
    justify-self: end;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #042440;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .scrolled-button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #042440;
  }
  .center-content-hero {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .center-content-hero-text-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .center-hero-img-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .center-hero-img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-title-hero {
    font-size: calc(8.5vw);
  }
  .main-subtitle-hero {
    font-size: calc(3.6vw);
    width: 87%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 480px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .header-left {
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .header-right.active {
    display: grid;
    transform: translateX(0);
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #042440;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .header-link {
    color: white;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    order: 2;
    justify-self: end;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #042440;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .scrolled-button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #042440;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
  .main-title-hero {
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
  .main-subtitle-hero {
    font-size: calc(2.2vw);
    width: 87%;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" translate="no">

<head>
  <meta name="google" content="notranslate" fetchpriority="high">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" fetchpriority="high">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" fetchpriority="high">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" fetchpriority="high">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#042440">
  <!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
  <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#042440">
  <!-- Windows Phone -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#042440">
  <!-- iOS Safari -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" fetchpriority="high" href="media/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fit.css" fetchpriority="high">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Main Hero Section & Header Start -->
  <div id="hero-page">
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <div class="header" id="header">
      <div class="header-left">
        <img src="media/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="#hero-page" class="header-link">
          <h4 id="maintain-link">Maintain</h4>
        </a>
        <a class="header-link" href="circle.html">
          <h4 id="relocate-link">Relocate</h4>
        </a>
        <a class="header-link" href="circle.html">
          <h4 id="buy-link">Buy</h4>
        </a>
        <button class="btn">Contact Us</button>
      </div>
      <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger">☰</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Header End -->
    <div class="center-content-hero">
      <div class="center-content-hero-text-container">
        <h1 class="main-title-hero">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text</h1>
        <h2 class="main-subtitle-hero">Dummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="center-hero-img-container">
        <img src="media/property-manager.jpg" alt="" class="center-hero-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip-separator-text-container">
      <h3 class="persona-banner">For overseas property owners</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Hero Section & Header End -->
</body>

</html>
```

Have I made some mistake on the CSS or is there something I am missing which I need to add for Chrome iOS only?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/anthonypena97/chromeios-viewportfitcover

Comment: Hi, I did, but it uses a third party library as well as jQuery. I would like to stick to my simple html, css and js.